# Data Failes to pull showing null

Tags: laravel

Im building an api to pull user data using the Bearer token.The code works but the data failed to pull

```
  public function details()
  {
    $user = Auth::user();

    return response()->json([
        'status'=>'success',
        'message'=>'user detailes retrieved succesfully',
        'data' =>$user
        ] , 200);

  }
```

this is the Route

```
 Route::get('user_details','API\details@details');
```

Results from postman

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "user detailes retrieved succesfully",
"data": null
 }
```

Comment: And what can we do to help? You didn't provide any code for authorization so how we can now what are you doing with token?

Comment: im using postman and im passing the token as bearer token for  Authorization as Header

Comment: It means you are not logged in. Did you add the correct middleware guard? Are you using the correct route namespace? Provide more of your code (middleware, route file) or compare your code with official [API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1) You must be authenticated 
// 2) Add a middleware group to check if you are authenticated

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user_details','API\details@details');
});
```